# How to solve differential equation with absolute value?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm a newbie here, I want to solve this equation for my assignment:

```
mg - c x'[t] Abs[x'[t]] = m x''[t]
```

I'm using

```
DSolve[{mg - c x'[t] Abs[x'[t]] == m x''[t],x'[0]==0,x[0]==32000},x[t],t]
```

but Mathematica seems very slow to load.

**Questions:** is there any other way to solve the equation?

**Edit:** i've tried to change, but still doesn't work
[image]

Comment: You should check the boundary conditions: `x[0]== 32000` , `x'[0]` makes no sense!

Comment: The defintion of the ode is wrong: `mg - c x'[t] Abs[x'[t]] ==   m x''[t]`

Comment: i forgot to write x'[0]==0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you substitute `Abs[x'[t]]->Sqrt[x'[t]^2]` mathematica can evaluate the ode

```
DSolve[{mg - c x'[t] Sqrt[x'[t]^2] == m x''[t] }, x[t], t]
```

Unfortunately the solution cannot be adapted to the inital conditions `x'[0]==0, x[0]== 32000`

**workaraound**

The ode only depends on `x'[t],x''[t]`, the substitution `x'[t]->v[t]` and division by m gives

```
ode=9.81 - cdm  v[t] Sqrt[v[t]^2] ==   v'[t] (*g=9.81*)
```

now the ode only depends on parameters `cdm=c/m` , `v0` and can be solved numerically

```
V = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode,v[0] == v0 }, v, {t, 0, 10}, {v0, cdm}]
Plot[Table[V[ 0, cdm  ][t], {cdm, {0, .01, .1, .5, 1, 10}}], {t, 0, 1 }, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, PlotLabel -> "variation cdm"]
```

[image]

Comment: i've tried it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be the initial condition `x'[0]==0`.  You give numerical values for the initial conditions,   perhaps you can provide the parameter values  `m, g, c`too?

Comment: m is 70 kg, g is 9.81, c is 0.5

Comment: `X = NDSolveValue[{m g - c x'[t] Abs[x'[t]] == m x''[t], x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == 32000} /. {m -> 70, g -> 9.81, c -> .5}, x , {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[X[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thank you so much!